# Fubini's Theorem: Stein and Shakarchi RA Book

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Stein and Shakarchi state Fubini's Theorem in "Real Analysis" as:

"Suppose $f(x,y)$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R}^{d^1} \times \mathbb{R}^{d^2}$ (where $x$ lives in the former and $y$ in the latter). Then, for almost every $y \in \mathbb{R}^{d^2}$

(a) $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d^1}} |f^y(x)| < \infty $

(b) the function defined by  $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d^1}} f^y(x)dx$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R^{d^2}}$.

(c)  $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d^2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d^1}} f^y(x)dxdy = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} f dx dy$ "

Now, I am able to understand what (a) means - simply, holding $y$ as a constant, the slice $f^y(x)$ is integrable $\mathbb{R^{d^1}}$. However, I do not understand what it means for the function $F(y) = $$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d^1}} f^y(x)dx $ from (b) to be integrable for a.e. $y \in \mathbb{R^{d^2}}$. Isn't integrability a global rather than local property w.r.t. the variable of integration? I did suppose it could mean that, there could exist some $y_i$ in some null-set $A \in \mathbb{R^{d^2}}$ such that $\int_{\mathbb{R^{d^2}}} |F(y_i)| dy = \int_{\mathbb{R^{d^2}}} |\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d^1}} f^{y_i}(x)dx| dy = \infty$. But this sounds wrong to me because you are then integrating over a constant function $F(y_i)$ , not $F(y)$. Moreover, as long $F(y_i)$ has a non-zero value, this integral would evaluate to infinity, which seems wrong.

How do I make sense of (b) given the almost-everywhere property?

Comment: The wording is wrong. 'For almost every $y$' should appear within a).

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I see. Is the reasoning for this what I say above (about integrability being a "global" rather than "local" property?)